# Exit from REPL without killing background process

Tags: scala, sbt, daemon, read-eval-print-loop

I'm using sys.process inside REPL as kind of shell. There are many uses for scala in a shell. And I invoke some external programs, of course. But I discovered that I could not leave the REPL with a background proccess running. And if I kill the sbt by either Ctrl-C or sending signal, the background process is killed also. I'd like to leave sbt and keep all invoked processes running. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with SBT or Scala but with the child process you created. The child needs to "daemonize" to become independent of the parent process. How to do that depends on what kind of process you are invoking and which OS you are running on. On Linux, using the following script as a wrapper around whatever process you are calling works:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup $@ 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```